# oracle regexp_replace - remove space between specific words

Tags: regex, oracle, replace

Need some help in regexp_replace with Oracle. 
I have some names where the middle name initials are separated with Space. I have to remove that space only.

John E. W. Doe       --> John E.W. Doe
Jane W. B. Dane, Jr. --> Jane W.B. Dane, Jr.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: If this is not an exercise, how are you verifying you will always have 2 middle initials with periods (and first and last names that are not single letters with periods)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try with input `(.+\w+\.) (\w+\..+)` output `\1\2`

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(<column>,
    '(.+\w+\.) (\w+\..+)',
    '\1\2')
```

Where:

- `(.+\w+\.)` is the first capturing group and `.+\w+` matches every up to and including the first `.` preceded by word characters `\w`
- `(\w+\..+)` matches a spaced, then opens another capture group to search for any word `\w+` followed by `.`, from here any sequence of characters is allowed with `.+`

May potentially be more robust with `(.+\w+\.) ?(\w+\.(.+)?)`. which would allow for names like `John E. W.` to be found. See [this example](https://regex101.com/r/wwUmPH/1) for more details.

Comment: This is perfect. Can you explain how did you do that. I mean if you can explain the pattern

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution will not work on names with THREE (or more) initials. There is no simple way to fix that with the Oracle regexp engine.